# What do I do if there are no new missions in Jetpack Joyride and I'm still missing one star to be able to level up?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

I just finished another set of missions for Jetpack Joyride , but oddly I'm still missing one more star to be able to complete the set to level up. I have no new missions, so I guess I'm stuck. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

Basic troubleshooting:

Quit the app, double tap home, hold on Jetpack Joyride, and delete it. (This will not delete the game itself; it just stops running it) and then open it again and see what happens.

Otherwise I'd say un-install and re-install; this shouldn't lose your progress if it is connected to something like Game Center.

Comment: It worked! Uninstalling and reinstalling the game... Thanks

Comment: It didn't work for me... i just un-installed and re-installed and play until lvl 12 with 14,000 coins, then i quit and later play it again and i just had 4,000 coins... :( it's the thirth time :(

Comment: @Merx, if this answers your question, accept it as an answer, and consider upvoting it.